# What is the round tube mounted on the roof just behind the windshield of a PC-6?

Tags: feature-identification, fuselage, antenna

If you look at the below image:

[image: Pilatus PC-6 with three "antennas"]
(image source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pilatus_PC-6_B2H4.jpg))

There are three "antennas" mounted on the forward portion of the cabin roof. The two rear, wing-shaped ones probably are the COM1/2 antennas, but I'm clueless as to what the the straight vertical tube (circled in red) mounted directly behind the windshield could be. Can anyone tell me what it is ?

Comment: Close-up pictures of the object in question:
https://i0.wp.com/modeltalking.hobbyart.sk/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/IMG_0644_vyrez.jpg
In all pictures I could find, it is painted in the same color as the fuselage, which leads me to believe it is not in fact an antenna.

Comment: thanks @Wasserwaage for the picture and the bounty ! :) I don't think it's an antenna either, but I didn't know  how to better describe it.

Comment: The pictures of older PC-6 models here: http://www.pc-6.com/portergallery.htm show this object mounted on planes manufactured way before 2003, which was apparently the first year that ADS-B was used in general aviation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Dependent_Surveillance%E2%80%93Broadcast#United_States

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The vertical tube on top of the cabin is the fuel system vent mast:

[image: axonometry]

[image: item list]

[image: schematic]

Pictures are taken from an online copy of *Royal Australian Air Force Pilatus Porter Flight Manual*, Australian Air Publication 7211.001-1

[image: cover]

Comment: Almost posted a guess to that effect!  Then figured "no, an airplane with wing tanks probably won't be vented at the centerline"-- wrong!

Comment: I was sure it had to be either some weird static port mast, or a fuel vent. Oddly enough it's not easy to find PC-6 POHs online despite it being such an long lived and common plane.

Comment: ooooh, the fuel vent … thank you very much ! :) How do I award the bounty ? There's no bounty award button as mentioned in the help article ! :(

Comment: @quietflyer oh okay, thanks !

Comment: @Programmer You don't get to award the bounty. Since qq jkztd started the bounty, they will be able to award it. The button is under the checkmark (only visible to qq jkztd at the moment).

Comment: @Bianfable oh okay, makes sense that I can't award someone else's bounty - thanks for explaining ! :D